# Tensorflow Object Detection API taking forever to install in a Google Colab and failing

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to install the Tensorflow Object Detection API on a Google Colab and the part that installs the API, shown below, takes a very long time to execute (in excess of one hour) and eventually fails to install.

```
# Install the Object Detection API
%%bash
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install
```

To discover What I was doing wrong, I reverted to the "Eager Few Shot Object Detection Colab" example available at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb in a Google Colab Pro notebook, and the "python -m pip install" part hangs as well.  Normally, this Colab runs in under 10 minutes, but in Google PRO Colab it is not running at all.

I can't seem to pinpoint what is causing this installation to fail. Anyone has any idea why the Object Detection API is no longer installing on Google Colab notebooks?

Update... yesterday the installation took over two hours, and failes, and this is the output:

```
Processing /content/models/research
Collecting avro-python3
  Using cached avro-python3-1.10.2.tar.gz (38 kB)
Collecting apache-beam
  Using cached apache_beam-2.34.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (9.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (4.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (0.29.24)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (0.5.5)
Collecting tf-slim
  Using cached tf_slim-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (352 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycocotools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (2.0.2)
Collecting lvis
  Using cached lvis-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.1.5)
Collecting tf-models-official>=2.5.1
  Using cached tf_models_official-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting tensorflow_io
  Using cached tensorflow_io-0.22.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (22.7 MB)
Collecting keras==2.6.0
  Using cached keras-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-addons
  Using cached tensorflow_addons-0.15.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: kaggle>=1.3.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.5.12)
Requirement already satisfied: gin-config in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.5.0)
Collecting sacrebleu
  Using cached sacrebleu-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.4.8)
Collecting py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0
  Using cached py-cpuinfo-8.0.0.tar.gz (99 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-text>=2.7.0
  Using cached tensorflow_text-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.1.3)
Collecting seqeval
  Using cached seqeval-1.2.2.tar.gz (43 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.19.5)
Collecting sentencepiece
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.96-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-datasets in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.0.1)
Collecting tensorflow-model-optimization>=0.4.1
  Using cached tensorflow_model_optimization-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-hub>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.12.0)
Collecting opencv-python-headless
  Using cached opencv_python_headless-4.5.4.58-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (47.6 MB)
Collecting tensorflow>=2.7.0
  Using cached tensorflow-2.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (489.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client>=1.6.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.12.8)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (596 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth>=1.16.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.35.0)
Requirement already satisfied: uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.26.3)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<1dev,>=0.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-httplib2>=0.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.53.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-slugify in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.62.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from packaging>=14.3->google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.0.4)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of six to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Using cached six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scipy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.7.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (38.2 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of six to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.5 MB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached scipy-1.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.5 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27.4 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27.4 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27.4 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27.4 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scipy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.5.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.5.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9 MB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.4.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.3.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.3.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.3.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.2 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.2.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.2.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (24.8 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.6 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (31.2 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.0.1.tar.gz (15.5 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.0.0.tar.gz (15.2 MB)
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz (14.1 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of rsa to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.7-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.6-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of rsa to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached rsa-4.2.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.1-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
  Using cached rsa-4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached rsa-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
  Using cached rsa-3.1.4.tar.gz (36 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of idna to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
  Using cached idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
  Using cached idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
  Using cached idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
  Using cached idna-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of chardet to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of idna to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Downloading chardet-3.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting certifi
  Downloading certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of chardet to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Downloading certifi-2020.11.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Downloading certifi-2020.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2019.6.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
  Downloading certifi-2019.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
  DEPRECATION: A future pip version will change local packages to be built in-place without first copying to a temporary directory. We recommend you use --use-feature=in-tree-build to test your packages with this new behavior before it becomes the default.
   pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7555.
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 199, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 319, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 128, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 384, in resolve
    raise ResolutionTooDeep(max_rounds)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 2000000
```

Ivan

Comment: I am having the same issue on Colab Pro +. Tried running the same notebook with Colab (non-pro) but it doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem with

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10375).

Comment: This did the trick. Installation takes 2 minutes, even though I get some errors at the end... it seems to work.  The error I get is:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
multiprocess 0.70.12.2 requires dill>=0.3.4, but you have dill 0.3.1.1 which is incompatible.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires requests~=2.23.0, but you have requests 2.26.0 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.